# Ordenar SQL por coincidencias en el where

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, oracle-11g

necesito hacer una consulta donde al buscar "Pepito Perez" me aparezcan por orden de maximas coincidencias. Ejemplo. En este caso el id 4 tiene dos coincidencias, pero si lo busco por id me aparece entre los ultimos y si le pongo por nombre de nompre no me aparece de primero. Necesito que el 4 que tiene mayor coincidencias aparezca de primero. Aqui un ejemplo

```
SELECT
  nombre1,nombre2,apellido1,apellido2
FROM
  persona
WHERE
  nombre1 LIKE "%pepito%" OR nombre1 LIKE "%perez%" OR 
  nombre2 LIKE "%pepito%" OR nombre2 LIKE "%perez%" OR
  apellido1 LIKE "%pepito%" OR apellido1 LIKE "%perez%" OR
  apellido2 LIKE "%pepito%" OR apellido2 LIKE "%perez%"
```

Aqui un ejemplo de los datos como los retorna

```
|id|nombre1|nombre2 |apellido1|apellido2|
| 1|Alfredo|andres  |Perez    |Gutierrez|
| 2|Monica |Andrea  |Perez    |Castaño  |
| 3|Pepito |Fernando|Garcez   |Burbano  |
| 4|Pepito |Alfredo |Perez    |Lopez    |
| 5|Jaime  |Alberto |Castaño  |Perez    |
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que antes que nada elijas la etiqueta correcta, ya que cada lenguaje de base de datos funciona de una manera... No es lo mismo hacerlo en mysql que en oracle. Pon el lenguaje que realmente estás utilizando

Comment: Pues he tenido el mismo problema tanto en MYSQL como en POSTRGES.

Comment: Ese es el problema. Como decirle que encuentre el registro con mas coincidencias y que ese registro sea el que aparezca de primero

Comment: [Order by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) Te recomiendo ver eso, y también [Group by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Comment: No @Benito-B. Por lo general las bases de datos no ordenan de ninguna forma los datos y no se debe de confiar en ningún orden si no existe un ORDER BY.

Answer (score 1):

Esto puede ser pesado de programar si el número de comparaciones varía, pero dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo.

```
SELECT
  nombre1,nombre2,apellido1,apellido2,
  CASE WHEN nombre1 LIKE "%pepito%"   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN nombre1 LIKE "%perez%"    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN nombre2 LIKE "%pepito%"   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN nombre2 LIKE "%perez%"    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN apellido1 LIKE "%pepito%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN apellido1 LIKE "%perez%"  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN apellido2 LIKE "%pepito%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
  CASE WHEN apellido2 LIKE "%perez%"  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  AS coincidencias
FROM
  persona
WHERE
  nombre1 LIKE "%pepito%" OR nombre1 LIKE "%perez%" OR 
  nombre2 LIKE "%pepito%" OR nombre2 LIKE "%perez%" OR
  apellido1 LIKE "%pepito%" OR apellido1 LIKE "%perez%" OR
  apellido2 LIKE "%pepito%" OR apellido2 LIKE "%perez%"
ORDER BY coincidencias DESC;
```

También puedes poner la operación directamente en el `ORDER BY` si no quieres mostrar el número de coincidencias.

Comment: Gracias, esto era lo que estaba buscando

Answer (score 0):

Esta seria la mejor respuesta

```
SELECT
  nombre1,nombre2,apellido1,apellido2
FROM
  persona
WHERE
  nombre1 LIKE "%pepito%" OR nombre1 LIKE "%perez%" OR 
  nombre2 LIKE "%pepito%" OR nombre2 LIKE "%perez%" OR
  apellido1 LIKE "%pepito%" OR apellido1 LIKE "%perez%" OR
  apellido2 LIKE "%pepito%" OR apellido2 LIKE "%perez%"
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN nombre1 LIKE "%pepito%"   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN nombre1 LIKE "%perez%"    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN nombre2 LIKE "%pepito%"   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN nombre2 LIKE "%perez%"    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN apellido1 LIKE "%pepito%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN apellido1 LIKE "%perez%"  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
  CASE WHEN apellido2 LIKE "%pepito%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
  CASE WHEN apellido2 LIKE "%perez%"  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC;
```

Comment: ¿por qué?, recuerda leer [answer] pues un aporte que es solo código se considera de baja calidad, si editas y argumentas el por que es la mejor te lo agradeceremos